# GraphQL returns field access exception although it is defined

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I have this schema defined.

```
input TopicInput {
  name: String!
  value: String!
}

input RetentionChangeInput {
  templateId: String!
  endDateAndTime: String!
  reason: String!
  topics: [TopicInput!]!
}

type Mutation {
  retentionChange(spec: RetentionChangeInput!): RetentionChangeResult!
}

type RetentionChangeResult {
  numberOfHits: Int!
}
```

Also this is my query file.

```
mutation ($templateId: String!, $endDateAndTime: String!, $reason: String!, $topics: [TopicInput!]!) {
  retentionChange(spec: {
    templateId: $templateId,
    endDateAndTime: $endDateAndTime,
    reason: $reason,
    topics: $topics
  }) {
    numberOfHits
  }
}
```

And I am performing mutation request using java.

```
return graphQlClient.documentName("mutationQuery")
                .variables(Map.of("templateId", request.templateId(), "endDateAndTime",                  request.endDateAndTime(), "reason", request.reason(), "topics", request.topics()))
                .execute()
                .map(resp -> resp.toEntity(Response.class))
                .block();
```

My request is looking like this

```
mutation {
    retentionChange(
        spec: {
            templateId: "11bf1735"
            endDateAndTime: "2029-02-01T12:00:00"
            reason: "Request"
            topics: [
                { name: "SER", value: "a7d6e86d" }
            ]
        }
    ) {
        numberOfHits
    }
}
```

And I am getting this error
org.springframework.graphql.client.FieldAccessException: Invalid field '', errors: [{message=Validation error (UnknownType) : Unknown type 'TopicInput', locations=[{line=1, column=87}], extensions={classification=ValidationError}}]